# Scss, nth-child & :not() selector

Tags: css, sass

I'm a bit new to scss and I have this basic style for rows in my rows container.

```
.rows-container{
    border-bottom:2px ridge grey;
}
.row{
    height:30px;width:100%;

    &:hover div{
        background-color:lightgrey;
        }
    &:nth-child(odd){
        background: white;
        }
    &:nth-child(even){
        background: #e0e0e0;
        }
}
```

pretty straight forward with the following html: i have left out some html that is not important.

```
<div class="rows-container">
    <div class="row></div> //white
    <div class="row></div> //grey
    <div class="row></div> //white
    <div class="row></div> //grey etc...
</div>
```

But now I have added child rows

```
<div class="rows-container">
    {{each rows}}
        <div class="row"></div>           //parent row

        {{each childs}}
        <div class="subitem"></div>   //several rows from the same table which have a parent_id connected to the current row.
        {{#each}}

    {{#each}}
</div>
```

I am planning to toggle the subitems on click. But when no subitems are visible (subitems have a color of their own), the '.rows' odd/even is messed up. Now I think this is caused because the nth-child odd/even is calculated on all rows/subitems in the container, and not just the .row(s). 
Is there a way to odd/even style the .rows, but exclude .subitems from the odd/even rotation?  I was thinking that maybe there is a way to use :not() in scss, but so far I have not succeeded.

Comment: Make the subitems children of the rows?

Comment: if I realy have to I suppose I could, but it messes up the whole responsiveness of the rows. Right now I am thinking jquery... I can create a .js file for css related things

Comment: CSS does not have a `nth-of-class` selector, so you wouldn't be able to select every other of a class.

Comment: I would accept that as an answer, I will find a way np

Comment: @MaartenKuijper you could make the `.rows` `<section>` and children `<div>`. Being different tags allow you more control by doing something like this: `section:nth-of-type(even)` . Now `<div>` would not be included in the selection, only `<section>`

Comment: awesome, never used section before, but it seems like a lifesaver

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `:nth-of-type`

so your code should be:

```
.row{
    height:30px;width:100%;

    &:hover div{
        background-color:lightgrey;
        }
    &:nth-of-type(odd){
        background: white;
        }
    &:nth-of-type(even){
        background: #e0e0e0;
        }
}
```

> REF: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/

```css
.subitem:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: lightslategrey;
}

.subitem:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="subitem">subitem</div>
<div class="">subitem no class</div>
<div class="">subitem no class</div>
<div class="subitem">subitem</div>
<div class="subitem">subitem</div>
<div class="">subitem no class</div>
<div class="">subitem no class</div>
<div class="subitem">subitem</div>
<div class="">subitem no class</div>
<div class="">subitem no class</div>
```

Comment: Tnx,  I am using the nth-of-type(odd/even) on the .rows now and have wrapped the subitems in a <section>  it seems fixed now!

Comment: @MaartenKuijper Cool =D

Answer (score 3):

**As I already commented:** If you make your `.row` into `<section>` and keep the siblings (they are on the same level (next to each other) not nested inside of `.row`) as `<div>`, you can maintain the odd/even sequence on the `.row` by using:

> section:nth-of-type(odd)

Using `:nth-of-type()` selector allows you to more control by using different tags which when used strategically, will allow you to specifically target tags.

### Demo

```css
section:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)
}

section:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: rgba(200, 0, 0, .4)
}
```

```html
<div class="rows-container">
  <section class="row">ROW1</section>
  <div>DIV</div>
  <section class="row">ROW2</section>
  <div>DIV</div>
  <div>DIV All divs are not children of any .row</div>
  <div>DIV All divs are siblings of the .row</div>
  <section class="row">ROW3</section>
  <div>DIV</div>
  <section class="row">ROW4</section>
  <div>DIV</div>
  <div>DIV</div>
  <section class="row">ROW5</section>
  <div>DIV</div>
  <section class="row">ROW6</section>
  <div>DIV</div>
  <div>DIV</div>
  <div>DIV</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tnx, I have used both features, but just a little bit differend,  .row:nth-of-type(odd/even),  and wrapped all the .subitem inside a section like:  <section><div subitem></div><div subitem></div><div subitem></div></section>. Now it is also very easy for me to create a clickfunction to toggle the right section connected to row

Comment: Indeed, you could do some alternating colors on subitems as well and change their colors according to the parent section for contrast. Like white sections open up to black subitems and vice versa.